# onAnimationComplete is executed before animation is done

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I use [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) for my charts and want to use `.toDataURL` on the canvas.

I try to get the URL after the animation is completed by callback function [onAnimationCompleted](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-animation-configuration), but my URL contains an empty image. If I put an alert (see comment), the alert is shown before the animation is visually done.

Here's the HTML

```
<h1>Chart as img</h1>
<img id="foobar" src="" />

<h1>Original Canvas</h1>
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

and JS:

```
var ctx = $("#myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue",],
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                12,
                19
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        onAnimationComplete: done(),
    }
});

function done() {
    var url = document.getElementById("myChart").toDataURL();
    // alert(url);
    $("#foobar").attr("src", url);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tjgf582/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Don't *call* the `done` function.

```
options: {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    onAnimationComplete: done // <--- no parentheses!
}
```

Comment: If I do this no alert happens. The function is not executed. I have the same behaviour if I do e.g. `onAnimationComplete: function() {alert("Completed!")}`. In this case the alert is also not showing up. But this shows me that there is somewhere an additional error in the script.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's happening because your function is being `called` directly when the script is executed in the browser. That's not a callback. You can try this:

```
var done = function () {
    var url = document.getElementById("myChart").toDataURL();
    // alert(url);
    $("#foobar").attr("src", url);
}
```

And further:

```
//Notice how I am using the variable instead of calling the function.
onAnimationComplete: done
```